# Mongodb: count occurence of a list of elements in an array of elements

Tags: mongodb-query, mongodb-java, spring-mongodb

Initial condition:

- a collection of travellers with an array of cities
- a list of destinations (cities).

How retrieve all travellers, that have three cities out the destination list?
At the moment I am only able to count the total number of destinations of a traveller...

```
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("destinations", new BasicDBObject("$exists", true));

    query.put("country.$id", countryId);
    query.put("$where","this.destinations.length <= " + maxNumDestinations);

    DB db = getMongoDbFactory().getDb();
    DBCollection travellerCollection = db.getCollection("traveller");
    DBCursor cursor = travellerCollection.find(query);
    return cursor;
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried and where you have failed.

Comment: I resolved the count for only one destination (city) in the array, but have no idea how to count these muliple occurences

Comment: You should post your code.